# Cytoscape Desktop: Hide unselected edges in filter?

Tags: cytoscape

I have a Cytoscape 3.4.0 graph with many edges and thus created a selection filter.

I set the style color of unselected edges to the background color but they still obstruct the selected edges.

Is it possible to hide unselected edges completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Control Panel* -> *Style* -> *Edge*. Click on *Properties* and check *Visible*. Go to *Visible*, set *Column* to *selected*, *Mapping Type* to *Discrete Mapping* and map *true* to *true* and *false* to *false*. This may bug out and not display the mapping key for *true*, in that case either set the default value to *true* first or select a different column and then set the mapping again.